# How to transfer SQLite db to web server on android phone

Tags: android, sqlite, webserver

I have an application that creates an SQLite database and saves
information to it over the course of a day. At the end of the day i
want to export this database to a web server.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Should I use httppost or put. I have researched this myself online but
there seems to be so many different ways to explore. The server side
does not exist yet either. I have access to an apache server so i am
hoping to use that.

Could anyone advise me the best/most simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using alternate means to the http protocol, such as FTP or, even better, SCP? Why do you want to go through http, is there a specific reason?

Comment: http was just the method i have seen most in my research. I think ftp would be an ideal way if possible, but i havnt found much to show me how to use ftp? Sorry if i sound clueless, im pretty new to this.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the goal of that backup, there is a [backupmanager class for API 8+](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#Testing) which could make your life significantly easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys,
Just wanted to let you know that i used the intent provided by the andFTP app in the end. Its very simple to use and details can be found at: http://www.lysesoft.com/support/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=158

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways ...

- you can ftp up the db each day
- you can export the data to a csv file and post it to the server; once there you can then import it into the db on the web server

Is it for backup purposes? Or do you require a number of dbs on the web server?

Comment: I will require a number of dbs on the server. The idea is that an application running on the server will use the information in the dbs each day. And i will want to keep the dbs from each day. 

I didnt realise i could use ftp in android. That seems like my solution. Do you know of any resources/solutions i could use to get started?

Thanks

Comment: Edit - I said the application would be running on the server. It wont be, the application will be on someones computer and will use the dbs on the server

Comment: I've had a search about and found ftp app for andriod, but I'm yet to find an ftp api to hook into yet ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this to be an automatic or manual transfer? SQLite data is just a file, so ([from the SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html))... "If SQLite can read the disk file then it can read anything in the database. If the disk file and its directory are writable, then SQLite can change anything in the database. Database files can easily be copied onto a USB memory stick or emailed for sharing." So (provided everything your app needs is set up on the server) just move the file to the server.

Comment: I want it to be both! I'll want to transfer the db at a certain time every day. But for now, for demonstration purposes i want to be able to send it manually.

Thanks, that seems to confirm what westdiscgolf said. If its just a file then shouldnt ftp upload be relatively simple? Any resources would be appreciated!

Comment: If the data isn't sensitive, ftp is fine. If it is, sftp will do. It should be a simple matter to set up a timed script within Android to: check for a connection, then connect and upload the SQLite data file to the server periodically. See AlarmManager: http://www.androidguys.com/2009/04/02/wake-up-with-the-alarm/.